# WCF service hosted through console need to be rehosted every time on machine restart

Tags: wcf

Not sure why service is showing a weired behavior, Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does rehosted mean? Does it mean that you have to run console application each time you restart the machine? That is obvious behavior - when application doesn't run, it cannot host WCF service. If you want your service to be automatically hosted after machine restart you have to host it in Windows service (and set the service to automatically start).